# If the fiber and the base are Kähler manifolds is the total space also Kähler?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, kahler-manifolds

Let $E$ be a compact manifold and consider the fiber bundle
$$F\to E\to B$$
Assume that $F$ and $B$ are Kähler manifolds. Is $E$ also a Kähler  manifold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be the standard Hopf surface $(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\})/\mathbb{Z}$ where the $\mathbb{Z}$-action is generated by the map $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (2z_1, 2z_2)$. There is a holomorphic submersion $\pi : H \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ given by $[(z_1, z_2)] \mapsto [z_1, z_2]$, so $\pi$ is a holomorphic fibre bundle. The fiber of $\pi$ over $[1, 0]$ is $C := \{[(w, 0)] : w \in \mathbb{C}^*\} \cong \mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{Z}$ where the $\mathbb{Z}$-action is given by $w \mapsto 2w$. This is a one-dimensional compact complex submanifold of $H$, namely a torus. So $\pi : H \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ is a holomorphic fibre bundle with fibre a torus.

Note that tori and $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are Kähler manifolds, but $H$ is not because it is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$ and $H^2(S^1\times S^3; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$. Topologically, we have taken the product of the standard Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$ with a circle to obtain $S^1\times S^1 \to S^1\times S^3 \to S^2$.

---

More generally, if $F$ and $B$ are manifolds which admit Kähler metrics, and $F \to E \to B$ is a fibre bundle, then $E$ may not even be orientable. For example, the Klein bottle $K$ is an $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$ so there is a fibration $S^1\times S^1 \to K\times K \to S^1\times S^1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if the manifolds $E,\ F, \ B$ are complex manifolds or/and simply connected?

Comment: @AmratA: They are complex manifolds in my example. I am not sure if one further assumes they are simply connected, I'd have to think about it.

Comment: Then Thanks in advance

Comment: For simply connected counterexamples, consider the twistor fibration $S^2 \to Z \to X$ where $X$ is any compact complex surface blown up at sufficiently many points so as to admit an anti-self-dual metric (by Taubes) providing the total space $Z$ with a complex structure. By a result of Hitchin, $Z$ does not admit a Kähler metric. The base manifold $X$ admits a Kähler metric (any simply connected closed four-manifold admitting a complex structure also admits a Kähler metric), as does $S^2$.

Comment: Actually the above argument is wrong. It only shows that $Z$ with the standard complex structure it inherits as a twistor space, is not Kähler. That is the content of the result of Hitchin being used. There is a priori no reason I can think of that $Z$ is not diffeomorphic to some Kähler manifold. For example, even though the twistor space over $T^4$ is diffeomorphic to $T^4 \times S^2$, which carries a Kähler metric, the complex structure it naturally has is not Kähler.

Comment: There is also the following point: in Hitchin's sense, the natural (or rather, one of the two natural, this one being known as the "Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer" one) almost complex structure on the twistor space over a Riemannian four-manifold is integrable iff the four-manifold is self-dual. Meanwhile, Taubes' result discusses anti-self-dual metrics. It seems to me OP is not taking the manifolds to have a background orientation, but if so, this causes an additional issue as one can not reverse orientations to combine Hitchin and Taubes while still having a complex manifold (e.g. consider $CP^2$).

Answer (score 1):

The book [Algebraic Geometry II, part 2 Algebraic Surfaces by Shafarevich and Iskovskikh](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642646072) answers this question in section 14.3 (p. 241) with the example of a specific type of Hopf surface

$$ (\mathbf C^2\smallsetminus 0) / \langle T\rangle$$

where

$$T(z_1,z_2) = (\alpha z_1, \alpha z_2)$$
 for some $$|\alpha|<1$$

as it maps to $\mathbf P^1$ via

$$(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (z_1,z_2)$$

with fibres elliptic curves $E$.