# Projective fibration over a projective manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $B$ be a complex projective manifold, consider a smooth fibration $\pi:X\rightarrow B$ such that all the fibers of $\pi$ are projective manifolds, then is $X$ a projective manifold?
As we know, if $X,Y$ are projective manifolds, then the product $X\times Y$ is also a projective manifold, see for example Griffiths&Harris 《principles of algebraic geometry》 p192. And this example can be treated as a special case of the question stated above, I doubt that the projective fibration over a projective manifold is also a projective manifold, is that right? May someone prove it or construct a counter-example? Any comment is welcome!

Added: in《principles of algebraic geometry》p191-192, the corollary after the Kodaira embedding theorem, Griffiths gave a proof that if $X,Y$ is projective, then $X \times Y$ is also projective. His method can be stated as follows: choose closed, integral, positive (1,1)-form $\omega,\omega^\prime$ of $X,Y$, and $\pi:X\times Y\rightarrow X$, $\pi\prime:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ are the projection maps, then $\pi^*\omega+\pi^{\prime*}\omega^\prime$ is again closed, integral, and positive of type (1,1), which proved that $X\times Y$ is also projective by Kodaira embedding theorem. I think the same method may work also for the projective fibration case? isn't it?

Comment: As a side remark, it is certainly true if B is a curve and (or?) all fibers are of low dimension (I think at most two?). I can look up a reference of that helps you. I‘m also looking forward to seeing some counterexamples in higher dimension.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are examples of smooth proper algebraic spaces which fibre in (projective) K3 surfaces over some smooth curve. Try searching MathOverflow for such  "families of K3 surfaces".

Comment: @sampleuser, someone told me that the Hopf surface is a fibration over $\mathbb P_1$ with fiber an elliptic curve. So do you have any reference which prove that when $B$ is a curve, it is true?

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar, maybe the Hopf surface already provides an counter-example.

Comment: @Tom yes it does. What sampleuser says is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, the original Hopf surface $H$ provides a counterexample. Recall, $H$ is defined to be the quotient $(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\})/\mathbb{Z}$ where the $\mathbb{Z}$ action is generated by the map $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (2z_1, 2z_2)$. The map $\pi : H \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ given by $[(z_1, z_2)] \mapsto [z_1, z_2]$ is a holomorphic submersion with fibers one-dimensional complex tori, as is explained in my answer to [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3405041/39599).

Note that one-dimensional complex tori and $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are algebraic, but $H$ is not even Kahler as it is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$. Topologically, we have the fiber bundle $S^1\times S^1 \to S^1\times S^3 \to S^2$ obtained by crossing the Hopf fibration with $S^1 \to S^1 \to *$.

One can obtain similar examples in higher dimensions, namely [Calabi-Eckmann manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Eckmann_manifold) which are complex manifolds $X$ diffeomorphic to $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}$ and admit a holomorphic submersion $X \to \mathbb{CP}^n\times\mathbb{CP}^m$ with fibers one-dimensional complex tori. Topologically, we have $S^1\times S^1 \to S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1} \to \mathbb{CP}^n\times\mathbb{CP}^m$, the product of the standard fibre bundles $S^1 \to S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ and $S^1 \to S^{2m+1} \to \mathbb{CP}^m$.

Comment: If the fibers are simply connected projective manifolds, it the total space a projective manifold?

Comment: No. See Aleksander Milivojevic's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405041/if-the-fiber-and-the-base-are-k%c3%a4hler-manifolds-is-the-total-space-also-k%c3%a4hler#comment7049362_3405104).

Comment: Aleksander Milivojevic's example is a Kähler manifold, but here we talk about a projective manifold, so they are different cases?

Comment: Projective manifolds are Kähler, so his counterexample applies here.

Comment: Projective manifolds are Kähler, but Kähler manifolds are not necessarily projective, Milivojevic only provide a maybe non-projective Kähler example, but didn't treat the projective case, so it's not enough to provide an counter-example.

Comment: You have misunderstood. In his counterexample he states "$X$ is any compact complex surface blown up at sufficiently many points". In particular, one can form examples where $X$ is projective, e.g. $\mathbb{CP}^2$ blownup at some points.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I have misunderstood.

Comment: That comment of mine actually did not show what was claimed (I added some new comments there elaborating), but what it did show still applies in the situation here.